# What a disappointment!

Tags: riddle

At first I heard it and thought i could soar like a bird!

And oh what i heard!

I’ll zoom so fast, my image will be blurred.

And now I see it, it’s flat as can be!

Oh woe is me.

And how lonely, just one single tree.

---

What is this riddle referring to?

**Hints:**

> The answer is a single word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is

> plain.

"thought I could soar like a bird"

> You misheard it as "plane". Planes (aeroplanes) fly.

"I'll zoom so fast, my image will be blurred."

> Just a reference to the rapid motion of aeroplanes? Or perhaps also a reference to the focal plane of a camera lens. (The reference to *zooming* suggests it might be.)

"it's flat as can be!"

> "Plain" means, among other things, flat. Of course you should have suspected this even when you had only heard the word and thought it was "plane": a plane (in the mathematical sense) is flat :-).

"just one single tree"

> A plane is also a kind of tree, but we're back to "plain" here so perhaps it's a plain ol' plane tree: just one single boring plane tree. Or (and this turns out to be the questioner's intention) I find myself on a plain, where by definition there are few trees.

Comment: A short explanation would be good to explain your answer. It is correct though!

Comment: Yup. I posted the answer first, then put in explanations.

Comment: I realise your answer is slightly off. The phrases "At first I heard it" and "And now I see it" are crucial to the poem.

Comment: Hmm. It could be heard as "plane" but then seen as "plain" which also means flat -- but the tree is definitely "plane" not "plain"...

Comment: You are on the right track with plain

Comment: So, just for my peace of mind, can you please confirm that you know that there is a kind of tree called a "plane" and there isn't a kind of tree called a "plain"?

Comment: There is a type of tree called a plane, but the tree is interpreted in context

Comment: Well, OK. How does it look now? I suspect I am still missing something with the tree, though.

Comment: A plain has a few meanings, i suggest you look through all of them.

Comment: I did. But I'll do it again. (Unless you just mean that on the kind of terrain called a "plain" there are usually few trees, in which case maybe we're done but I must register a mild protest at the specificity of "just one single ..." :-).)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have been so specific then :-). The terrain and the scarcity of trees was what I was describing.

Comment: OK, I did it again and don't see anything better than that. (Plain, n., means: a tract of flat land; more specifically, an expanse of grassy and largely treeless land; a meadow, field, or forest clearing; an open space in a town; an open space where a battle takes place; a flat surface; a flat part of any object; anything plain and simple; a kind of rough unpatterned fabric; a lamentation. Plus a few super-obscure obsolete meanings.)

Comment: OK, will tweak my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a poem then a riddle.
It could be

> A Dream

At first I heard it and thought i could soar like a bird!

> At start you saw something exciting in the dream thats what *"i heard it"* is referring to. And then you decided to fly into the dream like a bird.

And oh what i heard!

> Suddenly you saw someone in the dream

I’ll zoom so fast, my image will be blurred.

> Then decided to see him clearly(zoom) but its blurred.  Well all dreams are a blurred image.

And now I see it, it’s flat as can be!

> Then suddenly wake up from a dream and sorted out that was not real. May be flat here refers to coming to the actual flat world.

Oh woe is me.
And how lonely, just one single tree.

> After waking up from dream you found yourself all alone again. *a single tree* represents loneliness.

Comment: Good try, but that's not it.